# Is it possible to create a pull request for an azure dev ops repo in vs code?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I'm trying to use vs code's new c# dev kit and .net maui stuff with our codebase that lives in azure dev ops. I have no problem doing any other git operation aside from making pr's. Is this just not possible? (which is wild in mid 2023).

Comment: Pull requests aren't a Git feature. They're a platform-specific feature.

Comment: What's the actual question and what did you try? You're asking for *ADO PRs*, not Git PRs,  so did you try VS Code's ADO extension? Git's PRs [are just notifications](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) and have nothing to do with what everyone else is calling a PR. Github PRs, Bitbucket PRs, ADO PRs are all features provided by the platform itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no. However, the visual studio "create pull request" for azure devops is literally just a link to the azure dev ops page and so I've created a small vs code extension to [handle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaxBrooks.CreateADOPR) it.